# Bldc motor driver compability

Tags: motor, driver, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, automation

I looking for a drive for my sensorless bldc motor for a project of mine.

1)Will I be able to drive my motor with ESC(electronic speed controllers) used to RC hobbyist powered by Smps.

2)what are the parameters should I look for if the ESC are compatible

This is the specification of the bldc motor I have.
-**Motor type**: BLDC sensor less motor
-**No. of poles**: 4
-**Nominal Input Power** : 160 W
-**Nominal Voltage**  : 24VDC
-**Nominal Speed** : 6000 rpm
-**Max input Power** : 176 W (max)
-**Max voltage** : 30 VDC
-**Nominal Current** : 6.3 Amps (approx)
-**Max current** : 8 Amps

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you will able to drive your motor with an ESC.
2. If you are buying a hobbyist ESC there are 2 main parameters. The maximum voltage and maximum current. Get an ESC with a max current of, at least, 10Apms as your motor can do 8Amps max.

There are other parameters you should consider but if it is just a hobby project any ESC will do.

Comment: How do I choose voltage rating? Which is not mentioned in the esc specs. Should I choose 8 cell compatible esc which sums up 26v since each cell is 3.3v? If am not wrong.

Comment: 99% of the ESCs are used with LIPO batteries. Each LIPO cell is 3.7v so if an ESC is design to work with 2-4 cell battery it means that the ESC can work in the range of 7.4v-14.8v (Probably more but this is guaranteed)

Comment: Anything intended to last long with LiPo cells would have to work up at least to the freshly charged voltage of 4.2 volts per cell, and not only at the 3.7v which occurs relatively late in the useful part of the curve.